# (Kotlin) How do I stop a delayed Handler from executing at all?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm creating a simple metronome app. Playing on repeat 4 beats with an accent on the first one. I'm using a delayed handler for this. But when I click on my stop button I would like that handler to stop, but looking at my logs in the terminal I still it getting executed. Can someone help me here, please.

I'm trying to use the function **mainHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)** , but when I check the logs the handler is still running.

The logs are these ones, included in the code:

**Log.d("measureCount", measureCount.toString())**

**Log.d("accentPlayed", (!accentPlayed && !stopButtonPressed).toString())**

In my terminal I still see them as being updated, meaning that the override fun run() from the handler is still executing. But here I would that process to stop without killing the app. Thanks

Code:

```
fun metronome() {

    var timer = 500

val timeSignatureTop = 4
    var accentPlayed = false
    var measureCount = 1

    val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    mainHandler.post(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {

            Log.d("measureCount", measureCount.toString())
            Log.d("accentPlayed", (!accentPlayed && !stopButtonPressed).toString())

            if (!accentPlayed && !stopButtonPressed) {
                mediaPlayerAccent!!.start()
                measureCount++
                accentPlayed = true
            }

            else if (measureCount < timeSignatureTop && !stopButtonPressed) {
                mediaPlayerBeat!!.start()
                measureCount++
            }

            else if (measureCount == timeSignatureTop && !stopButtonPressed) {
                mediaPlayerBeat!!.start()
                measureCount = 1
                accentPlayed = false
            }
            if (stopButtonPressed) mainHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)

            mainHandler.postDelayed(this, timer)
        }
    })
}
```

I'm trying to use the function mainHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) , but when I check the logs the handler is still running

Answer (score 0):

Right after you remove the callbacks, you call `postDelayed` so it has another callback again and the loop continues. You should put a `return` inside the if statement after removing the callbacks (you’ll need to add brackets).

In fact, if you do that and move this if statement to the start of your function, you won’t have to keep checking `isStopBuutonPressed` over and over.

By the way, I think this metronome is likely to build up error over time. I would probably try something like this to avoid that:

```
val nextTargetTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timer

mainHandler.post(object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {

        //…

        nextTargetTime += timer
        val delay = nextTargetTime - System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (delay < 0) {
            // can’t keep up, skip one
            nextTargetTime -= timer
        }
        mainHandler.postDelayed(this, delay)
```

With a coroutine, I think this kind of logic is easier to write, because you can use a while loop with a delay at the end, and just break out of the loop when you need to. Something like this:

```
val interval = 500L
val timeSignatureTop = 4
var measureCount = 0L

lifecycleScope.launch {
    var beatCount = 0L // beat is counted from 0 up to timeSignatureTop-1
    val nextTargetTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + interval

    fun incrementBeat() {
        beatCount = (beatCount + 1) % timeSignatureTop
        if (beatCount == 0) measureCount++
    }

    while (!stopButtonPressed) {
        val player = if (beatCount == 0) mediaPlayerAccent!! else mediaPlayerBeat!!
        player.start()

        nextTargetTime += interval
        val delay = nextTargetTime - System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (delay < 0) {
            // can’t keep up, skip one
            nextTargetTime -= interval
            incrementBeat()
        }
        delay(delay)
        incrementBeat()
    }
}
```

Comment: Another thing that I detected is that indeed as you suspected, on my simulator that metronome would is running at stable selected time intervals, but on my actual phone, it's a mess, the interval is not constant. I'm not sure what's happening so I have to investigate (I'm new to the concept of coroutines / threads, but any help would be appreciated. thanks)

Comment: I added an example of doing this with a coroutine. I think the logic is simpler because you can just use a `while (!stopButtonPressed)` loop.

Comment: For some reason the lifecycleScope.launch {} is not recognized in Android Studio (I did import the right library I think + updated dependencies). For instance if I'm using  GlobalScope.launch {} I don't get an error. Again I'm new with these corountines, trying to see what's wrong with that declaration: lifecycleScope.launch {}, seems like I need to create a variable val lifecycleScope but I don't know what initialization to give it exactly.

Comment: So far I tried with GlobalScope{}, the problem still persists, it's a bit more stable, but not quite there yet

Comment: I'm not sure if here we would need to set a priority condition on that coroutine or something like that...?

Comment: `lifecycleScope` is a property available for ComponentActivities (and subclasses like AppCompatActivity) and Fragments only. If your code is in a ViewModel, use `viewModelScope`. Otherwise, it is usually appropriate to either pass one of these scopes into a class's constructor or for your custom class to create its own CoroutineScope that it appropriately cancels when it is finished with it. You ABSOLUTELY SHOULD NOT use GlobalScope for this metronome because it will cause memory leaks and thread leaks.

Comment: I have never used coroutines or handlers for something that requires precise timing like a metronome. It may simply be that they are not suitable. You might have to spin up your own dedicated thread that has a loop and uses Thread.sleep() for intervals. Alternatively, the problem could be with MediaPlayer and how responsive it is about calling `start()` on it. You might want to research that. Like maybe it needs to be created on a certain thread and always have `start()` called on it on that same thread to keep it highly responsive.